# permutation question that has an "at least" restriction?

Tags: permutations

How many ways are there to seat six boys and seven girls in a row of chairs so that none of the girls sit together?

13P13 - (7P2x11P11 + 7P3x10P10 + 7P4x9P9 + 7P5x8P8 +7P6x7P7 + 7P7x6P6)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain "at least" in the heading in what context,, and what the expression in the body is supposed to count ?